# Style isn't working properly

Tags: wpf

While learning WPF, I've created a style, that applies rounded corners to a textbox and also set the background color, if the control has the focus:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="efTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate >
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

At runtime if the control gets the focus, the border is rendered as expected in red color, but the background color of the textbox doesn't change to blue.

What's wrong?

Comment: You forgot targetname=border. Right now it has nothing to set the background of.

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan as far as I understand the issue, Michael wants to change the textbox background, not the border's one.

Comment: Yeah but he replaced the controllertemplate. So what is the textbox in this template?

Comment: I was on the same page as enkryptor, but now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setter mus have a TargetName else it won't know where to set the value.
In your case:
`<Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>`

Answer (score 1):

That might sound a bit confusing, but for the Background you need your TargetName="border"

For the foreground on the other hand side, you wouldn't need:

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="efTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="bal">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="blue"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="yellow"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```